# Advance Poll block keeps caching results

Tags: 7, polls

We have begun testing the [Advanced Poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll) module. We are having an issue where the results from the very first vote are cached, and then all page views from that point are only the results of that single vote.

I need a way to make sure the blocks for the Advanced Poll are not cached.

We use Memcached, and everything I read on it is vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Lazy Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/lazy_pane) or [Block Lazyloader](https://www.drupal.org/project/blocklazyloader) modules to output your poll block. Your block will be loaded from the client side, on demand, via AJAX.